# Stuck on running Mule Jar file without Mule Runtime environment

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am using Mule 3.9 with Anypoint studio 7.2 for API development. After my functionality developed I was able to export to a Jar file which I was supposed to run on my hardware which doesnt support x64 architecture.
I got error of not supported architecture. So I am looking for solution in 2 ways.

1. As hardware architecture cant be changed, is there any way to still run Mule program on it without using Mule runtime environment.
2. Using exported Jar file is it possible to use it only without Mule installed on my hardware machine.

Thanks in advance.

As per comment See error message,when tried to run in Docker also.
[image]

Comment: Is running your code in Anypoint studio itself an option? Also, Anypoint studion 7.x is only supposed to be used with Mule 4 AFAIK

Comment: You missed to provide the actual error and describe your environment and architecture. Please provide the details. Otherwise the question is abstract and can not be answered.

Comment: Hi Harshank, I am running code in Anypoint studio for local development. But for deployment of the code on server I am using export Jar file

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for textual information. You should also describe the environment briefly. You didn't mention docker before.

Answer (score 1):

Mule uses the Java Service Wrapper to bootstrap the Mule runtime. At this time the version of the wrapper included with Mule previous to Mule 4.4 doesn't support aarch64 as an architecture, only 32 bits ARM (armhf). At this time only Mule 4.4 Enterprise Edition seems to has compatibility with armhf-64. You should try that version to see if aarch64 is recognized as armhf-64.

Also note that Studio 7.x is not compatible with Mule 3.x applications so it is not possible to use it to develop a Mule 3.9 application. You are saying that the deployment file is a jar file so it is clearly a Mule 4 application. A Mule 4 application can not be deployed to a Mule 3 server, they are not compatible.